# How to use =LEFT and =LEN function with scientific notation in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, scientific-notation

I'm trying to write an Excel macro using VBA that will return only the first 5 numbers in a cell when the length of that cell exceeds 20. The field normally returns 15-digit alphanumeric results (which I need to leave alone) but in certain exceptions will return a 5-digit number with a multitude of zeroes following it (1234500000000000000000000...) which Excel converts into scientific notation (1.2345E+160). I am able to convert the cells to numbers instead of scientific notation and view the whole number.

I've tried to use code such as =IF(LEN(A1)>20,LEFT(A1,5),A1) and it just returns 1.2345E+160. Even though the whole number is displaying, Excel still thinks the cell length is 11 and won't display the first 5 digits.

I've also tried lines such as =IF(A1="*E*",LEFT(A1,6),A1) thinking it would detect the E, return 1.2345, and I could just remove the decimal points, but that didn't work either (it just returns the original 1.2345E+160).

I got the same results whether the cell was formatted as number or text. Is there a way around this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288829/excels-len-function-returns-5-on-numbers-longer-than-20-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use string manipulation on a number. Instead use math:

```
=A1/1E+160
```

If you do actually want to treat this thing as text, understand that the underlying value being stored is your `12345000000000000...` and there is no decimal point in that thing. So you'll have to convert to text and add the decimal:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0"), 1) & "." & MID(TEXT(A1,"0"), 2, 4)
```

But that's pretty ugly. I would just stick with math.